# populate combobox with data from enum

Tags: c#, .net

I have enum

```
public enum MyEnum
{ 
   Choice = 1,
   Choicee = 2,
   Choiceee = 3
}
```

and I want to dynamically fill list with this enum values

```
var data = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
```

where `ComboBoxItem` has two properties, `Id` and `Name`. Id should be enum int value and name should be enum Value like Choice or Choicee, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Enum.GetValues` for it:

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SearchOption)).Cast<SearchOption>()
            .Select(x => new ComboBoxItem() { Id = (int)x, Name = x.ToString() }).ToList();
```

Comment: To just add to this answer: if your enum item names aren't suitable for putting out directly into a drop-down box then you could use attributes on the enums and look for those. e.g. FirstName, SourceLocation, SomeInternalReference